# Android working with canvas, bitmap, and imageview

Tags: android, canvas, android-imageview, android-bitmap

I am developing an application in which i have to take image from camera or gallery and on that image i have to sketch using figure touch by choosing color but it is not working properly when i am using large pixel image on touch it draws on top of imageview my code is

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnTouchListener {

ImageView choosenImageView;
Button choosePicture;
Button savePicture;

Bitmap bmp;
Bitmap bmp1;
Bitmap alteredBitmap;
Canvas canvas;
Paint paint;
Matrix matrix;
float downx = 0;
float downy = 0;
float upx = 0;
float upy = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    choosenImageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.ChoosenImageView);
    choosePicture = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.ChoosePictureButton);
    //savePicture = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.SavePictureButton);

    //savePicture.setOnClickListener(this);
    choosePicture.setOnClickListener(this);
    choosenImageView.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v == choosePicture) {
        Intent choosePictureIntent = new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        Log.d("Started","->");
        startActivityForResult(choosePictureIntent, 0);
    } else if (v == savePicture) {

        if (alteredBitmap != null) {
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues(3);
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "Draw On Me");

            Uri imageFileUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
            try {

                OutputStream imageFileOS = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(imageFileUri);
                alteredBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, imageFileOS);
                Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, "Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                t.show();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.v("EXCEPTION", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri imageFileUri = intent.getData();
        try {
            BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                    imageFileUri), null, bmpFactoryOptions);

            bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = 3; //calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);
            //bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(bmpFactoryOptions, choosenImageView.getWidth(), choosenImageView.getHeight());
            Log.i("inSampleSize","->"+calculateInSampleSize(bmpFactoryOptions, choosenImageView.getWidth(), choosenImageView.getHeight()));

            bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                    imageFileUri), null, bmpFactoryOptions);

            Log.d("Bitmap","crseated");
            alteredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(), bmp
                    .getHeight(), bmp.getConfig());
            canvas = new Canvas(alteredBitmap);

            //choosenImageView.draw(canvas);
            /*Bitmap result =Bitmap.createBitmap(alteredBitmap,choosenImageView.getLeft()+10, choosenImageView.getTop()+50,
                    choosenImageView.getWidth()-20, choosenImageView.getHeight()-100);*/
    //        alteredBitmap.recycle();

            paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
            matrix = new Matrix();
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, matrix, paint);

            choosenImageView.setImageBitmap(alteredBitmap);
            choosenImageView.setOnTouchListener(this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("ERROR", e.toString());
        }
    }
}

//Given the bitmap size and View size calculate a subsampling size (powers of 2)
static int calculateInSampleSize( BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    int inSampleSize = 1;   //Default subsampling size
    // See if image raw height and width is bigger than that of required view
    if (options.outHeight > reqHeight || options.outWidth > reqWidth) {
        //bigger
        final int halfHeight = options.outHeight / 2;
        final int halfWidth = options.outWidth / 2;
        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            downx = event.getX();
            downy = event.getY();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            upx = event.getX();
            upy = event.getY();
            canvas.drawLine(downx, downy, upx, upy, paint);
            choosenImageView.invalidate();
            downx = upx;
            downy = upy;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            upx = event.getX();
            upy = event.getY();
            canvas.drawLine(downx, downy, upx, upy, paint);
            choosenImageView.invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: on touch is not working properly. when i touch on imageview the line is draw on the top of touch axis

Comment: Your shift key does not work? Nor the dot key? You are not telling how it should be drawn. And still no questions.